# How to install app like nautilus open terminal in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: nautilus

The nautilus open terminal is not more available in Ubuntu 18.10? There is other app that replace it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that old package named `nautilus-open-terminal` were replaced in 18.04 LTS and in 18.10 to package named [`nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nautilus+terminal&searchon=names).

You can install it with

```
sudo apt install nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

And get *Open in Terminal* option back.